# Gender insults in comments

Tags: support, comments, gender

I've never asked a question here and I hope it's a good place to ask this.

Someone today asked a question, where I gave a logical answer. Then another person answered and accused me of copying his answer. Please review the edit history to see that the only person who can be accused of copying, is he (he changed the code to match my snippet, but I didn't care until he tried to accuse me.. but we have the edit history).

Later, in comments we were debating about the logs and the person stated:

> haha, you teach your users to get the syslogs? it's so funny, only a girl could say something like this

Btw: Obviously, I don't teach user to get the syslogs but to send packed and encrypted logs written by myself, saved into a special file. Anyway, this should not matter.

I feel offended and I have no idea what should I do. I don't need to explain myself to annonymous person in the internet when he doesn't try to understand, but it's so unfair.

What should I do?

Comment: flag as offensive? Then back off, no need to engage further

Comment: But it's not the question but the comment is offensive...

Comment: You can flag comments :). By them (to the left) is a little flag and a little up arrow. In general though, you should NOT even have engaged back when he taunted you there.

Comment: @Vive, also consider growing a thicker skin. You should not take offense to teenager-level comments like *it's so funny, only a girl could say something like this* (no offense to teenagers).

Comment: @Patrice Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it accepted? His offensive comments are already deleted (in fact the whole answer is o.O), thanks.

Comment: At SO we care about good and bad *posts*; other users **should not** be bringing up unrelated issues like your gender in evaluating your contributions, that's unacceptable here. Absolutely flag comments like this for moderator intervention.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I take offence to that, simply because it's a sexist comment which has no place on SO. Sure, it's just one comment - but imagine a world where you're bombarded with that sort of comment all the time. Death by a thousand paper cuts.

Comment: Flag as offensive, then leave it alone..,.

Comment: I understood Frédéric's comment to mean that assholes will be assholes, especially on the Internet, and we as a open-to-everyone community wll never be able to *completely* prevent them from being assholes (although we're really super fast cleaning stuff up) so it's important not to let them get to you too much on a personal level (yeah I know it's easier said than done.) There is no debate that it's completely unacceptable behaviour. Totally flag for mod attention whenever something like this happens, or as a last resort write to team@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Gender insults should be treated in the same way as any other type of abusive/offensive/insulting content: Flag it as offensive and move on. Engaging in any kind of interaction rarely (if ever) results in a positive outcome. Let the mods do their thing if the user continues to act in the same way.

Comment: This is the black-and-white of it: Two people were arguing. One of them took it too far. It could have been avoided. The fact that it could have been avoided is *by no means* a justification; merely an observation. Both parties involved should have backed off sooner. We're adults. Let's all act like it.

Comment: Sadly, this is a problem across the tech industry; flag the comment and hope for the best next time. This attitude will never change in some individuals; adopting a neutral or male username is the only way to neutralize this, in my experience. I know it's frustrating.

Comment: Well it is really rude, people writing such should get some harsh. But using the terminology of the current worst enemy of the humanity is bad.

Comment: After flagging, I would suggest not letting the other user's immaturity bother you.  If anything, take it as a compliment: Not only did they copy your code (imitation is the sincerest form of flattery; the fact that they tried to steal the credit doesn't change that they think your code is better than theirs), they couldn't find anything wrong with what you said even when they were specifically trying to find _anything whatsoever_ to criticise (and thus had to resort to sexism and petty childishness instead).  In fact, considering the "girl" comment, they may not even _understand_ your answer.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can and should flag such comments, whether sexist, racist, demeaning, or whatever. The "rude or offensive" flag is definitely appropriate in these instances.

To flag a comment, simply hover your mouse to the left of a comment, you will see both a flag and a triangle pointing up.

[image: Screenshot of this functionality]

Clicking on that flag will give you the following options :

[image: Screenshot of this functionality]

In general though, I would suggest not even engaging further whenever such a comment springs. Simply flagging and moving away is best for you. If there is a repeat history of rude comments from the same user, moderators will get involved and talk with them.

Comment: @NateBarbettini image not mine. I was on a phone when I answered, so too lazy for the print screen... but if I could downvote myself, I would. There is indeed a need for more hand-drawn red on that image.

Comment: @Patrice - [Something like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/A6MHA.png)

Comment: I hate this picture, it looks like the hover text got stuck and clicking around doesn't make it go way.

Comment: For a short but unnerving fraction of a second, I had a cognitive problem seeing two identical mouse cursors. To know what I mean - move your cursor over the picture near the cursor on the picture and leave it there to read something, then look back at them. Fun! or maybe I'm just tired..

Comment: Without experimenting. Is the comment immediately flagged when you click the flag or do you have to specify what's so offensive about it? =?

Comment: @Luminous it's automatically handled. If there is enough (no idea what the threshold is, I believe it's lower for rude and spam than it is for other types of flags), the comment will be deleted without a moderator action

Comment: @Luminous: You'll need to choose a reason from a list of options (or enter a custom reason). Beyond that there's not much to it. Which reason you choose doesn't have any meaningful effect on how many flags it takes to delete a comment (3, or 1 for comments with specific keywords) - it's mostly informative.

Comment: @Luminous Just read the "click" again and realized what you were asking. Edited the image in the answer showing the options :)

Comment: Woot! +1 to me for subtly encouraging you to improve the quality of your answer!

Comment: @Luminous ain't that what this whole site is about? ;) I sometimes forget simple things like "not everyone clicked on that before so they may not know what it'll do" :P. Thanks for reeling me in ^^

Comment: @BoltClock don't *offensive* flags carry a rep penalty on comments?

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski: No, only posts.

Comment: If you think *this* was bad, there was an even worse one I answered in the WorkPlace on some guy trying to prevent women from being hired. Obnoxious people out there. Flag 'em and move on.

Comment: @peterh Eh, what does beer have to do with this?

Comment: @eterh: Don't bump _old_ controversial questions like this for edits that are _that_ insignificant.