# To whom should users who spread consistently unhelpful or derogatory comments be reported?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

This doesn't come up too often, thankfully, but it does come up enough to warrant some type of process to address.

Specifically, I am talking about users who seemingly run around degrading or maligning other users answers through derogatory comments, etc. leaving comments that are unhelpful, and that appear to have no other purpose than to either (1) make the commenter feel better from some deep seated insecurity standpoint, or (2) are possibly intended to benefit their answer (if they provided one) by maligning the other answers on the same page.

Don't misunderstand. I'm not taking about critical comments that point out inaccuracy or inefficiency in an answer -- we all understand those are fine and what comments were intended for. I'm taking about comments that are nothing more than basically spreading FUD or are just so rude and derogatory as to have no professional or technical value.

There should be some channel where this type of behavior can be reported so that those who are tasked with making sure SO is technically informative and free from this type of distraction can look into these instances when they arise.

Answers can be flagged, but how do we handle this type of behavior in comments?

Comment: Comments can be flagged as being unconstructive.

Comment: _"Answers can be flagged, but how do we handle this type of behavior in comments?"_ Um... Flag the comments? Comments can be flagged as well, and all comment flags go straight to the mods. If a user has a habit of these comments and they are as bad as you claim, mods will start to see a pattern very quickly and will handle it.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308033/5240004

Comment: Crud -- I completely overlooked that feature. Sorry for my own FUD..

Comment: @Daedalus Please don't suggest which comment it might be. It doesn't help if everyone piles on adding inflammatory comments of their own.

Comment: @ChrisF Very well, I just didn't exactly agree it was derogatory, however, that's based on my own understanding of how that word is defined, and not the definition(as was defined by looking up the word to make sure).  Point being, I'm not going to press this.

Comment: Funny enough the flagging comments issue (specific: not knowing it is possible) comes up quite regularly it seems. I wonder if it would need a UI-change, clearly it is expected to find a 'flag' link to click and not a tiny icon which only appears when you hover.

Comment: Is this about me? I think this is about me. This is about me, isn't it? This is about me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first instance flag the comments for moderator attention. Use the "other" option to explain the situation. If you find yourself running out of space the flag the post itself but *make it clear you're concerned about the comments* as the moderators are not clairvoyants.

[image: how to flag a comment]

*(Image stolen from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308033/5240004))*

[image]

The moderators will deal with the situation appropriately.

Don't make it public. Other, possibly well meaning, users piling on adding their own comments can only make things worse.

Comment: Thanks - I had completely overlooked that. I apologize for my own FUD.

Comment: It's probably worth adding that people should not engage with the offender. Feeding trolls is never the answer. Freehand red circles, however, are always the answer.

Comment: @theB: Something to keep in mind for all you would-be Miss Stack Overflow contestants. "World peace... and freehand red circles!"